# removing strange clickboxes on image-link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make some buttons containing images.

But when I click them, a strange horizontal line appears, as well as a dotted bounding box on FF.

i have tried `outline: none;`,but it doesn't change anything...
how can i re-arrange the html (or edit the css) to fix this? I don't want those boxes (especially the horizontal one in the middle)

thanks

html

```
<div class="button frontbutton col-md-4">
     <a href="/tips">
         <img src="url.png" class="buttonPic">
         <span data-i18n="buttons.tips">Tips</span>
     </a>
</div>
```

css

```
.frontbutton {
  padding: 15px;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #444;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.62);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  color: #199ACE;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

img.buttonPic {
  width: 95%;
}
```

thanks [image: problem with the button]

https://jsfiddle.net/pLkyqz0x/

#### UPDATE

while making the fiddle, i noticed what caused the gray bar (box shadow on `a:active`)
but the red box on FF remains....

Comment: Please, add your jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the `a:focus { }` style. So you can remove it by setting `a:focus { outline: none; }` however this is not considered best practice as the focus style is an accessibility requirement. You should instead redefine focus styles that work for you. (For further reading on why this is bad practice: http://www.outlinenone.com/)

Comment: is there a way to leave it in for tabbing, but not show it when clicked? i have no problem with it EXISTING for screenreaders, tab etc, but it makes the button look really ugly for normal clicks

Comment: It's the same psuedo selector for both, so not in CSS. You can work around it using javascript by detecting the click event and applying a class name temporarily. I'd still fix the focus styles so they're acceptable looking though.